# DCEVM+HotSwap Agent with JBoss EAP 6 & JDK 7

Tags: java-7, jboss6.x, hotswap, dcevm, hotswapagent

I am trying toconfigure DCEVM + HotSwapAgent for my eclipse project which uses JDK 7 & JBoss EAP 6.0.

After Replacing DCEVM & adding following VM arguments - I am getting "`NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/modules/LocalModuleLoader`" during JBoss startup.

I tried following steps & encountered different error

- DCEVM 7u79 installer.jar with latest version of Hotswap agent (1.4.2 jar) and setting VM argument as `-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:<FULL\\WINDOWS\\PATH>hotswap-agent-1.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar=autoHotswap=true` --> I am getting " `org/hotswap/agent/HotswapAgent : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`"
- DCEVM 7u79 installer.jar with Hotswap agent (1.3.0 jar) and setting VM argument as `-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:<FULL\\WINDOWS\\PATH>hotswap-agent-1.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar=autoHotswap=true` --> I was getting "`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HotswapperPlugin`"
- DCEVM 7u79 installer.jar **without** Hotswap agent and setting VM argument as `-XXaltjvm=dcevm`  --> I was getting "`NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/modules/LocalModuleLoader`"
- Uninstalling DCEVM from JDK7 & no VM argument --> starts JBoss without any problem.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back from the death, but did you finally get to fix this?